# how to fetch json data and store it in an array in iphone app and access it

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using this code to access the json data.  It shows the two objects in array but then stops

```
SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://celeritas-solutions.com/emrapp/AppointmentListings.php"]];
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *object = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
//appDelegate.books = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

appDelegate.books = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSArray *results = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@", results);

for (int i=0; i<[results count]; i++) {
    AppointmentListing *aBook = [[AppointmentListing alloc] initWithDictionary:[results objectAtIndex:i]];
    [appDelegate.books addObject:aBook];
    [aBook release];    
}
```

Below is my json data

```
[{"ProviderNPI":"7610922880","PatientID":"556712","AppointmentDate":"2012-03-20","AppointmentTime":"09:00:00","AppointmentListingsID":"1","UpdateDateTime":"2012-03-20 00:30:35"},{"ProviderNPI":"7610922880","PatientID":"712211","AppointmentDate":"2012-03-20","AppointmentTime":"10:00:00","AppointmentListingsID":"2","UpdateDateTime":"2012-03-20 00:31:25"}]
```

Comment: `NSString *responseString = [request responseString];`
    `NSMutableDictionary *responseJSON = [responseString JSONValue];`. Then you can simply Use NSDictionary and display data from that.

Comment: @ParthBhatt how to do in this i have also given above code

Comment: Refer to this link: http://jasarien.com/?p=428

Comment: @Aftab Ali you just need to copy/paste the code I have posted in this page will all set for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just copy & paste  & replace to your code will solve your problem :

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://celeritas-solutions.com/emrapp/AppointmentListings.php"]];
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *books=[json_string JSONValue];

for (int i=0; i<[books count]; i++) {
    /*AppointmentListing  *aBook = [[AppointmentListing alloc] initWithDictionary:[books objectAtIndex:i]];
    [books addObject:aBook];
    [aBook release];*/

    NSDictionary *dict=[books objectAtIndex:i];

    book.appointmentdate=[dict valueForKey:@"AppointmentDate"];
    book.AppointmentListingsID=[dict valueForKey:@"AppointmentListingsID"];
    book.AppointmentTime=[dict valueForKey:@"AppointmentTime"];
    book.PatientID=[dict valueForKey:@"PatientID"];
    book.ProviderNPI=[dict valueForKey:@"ProviderNPI"];
    book.UpdateDateTime=[dict valueForKey:@"UpdateDateTime"];

    NSLog([dict description],nil);
}

NSLog(@"%@", json_string);


//May this will help you out.
//You just need to import "Json.h" to your class header


//Log I got from this piece of code :
2012-03-21 14:34:34.841 ProgressiveDownload[1045:f803] {
    AppointmentDate = "2012-03-20";
    AppointmentListingsID = 1;
    AppointmentTime = "09:00:00";
    PatientID = 556712;
    ProviderNPI = 7610922880;
    UpdateDateTime = "2012-03-20 00:30:35";
}

2012-03-21 14:34:37.356 ProgressiveDownload[1045:f803] {
    AppointmentDate = "2012-03-20";
    AppointmentListingsID = 2;
    AppointmentTime = "10:00:00";
    PatientID = 712211;
    ProviderNPI = 7610922880;
   UpdateDateTime = "2012-03-20 00:31:25";
}
```

Comment: but app is crashing when i am using this

Comment: Just look at above code, I got the log of the data downloaded.

Comment: yes now it is working but how may add these in an array like book.appointmentdate; like this i have NSObject class already made for this

Comment: Check the code now. Do confirm that you have declared all the variables you are using of that custom class.

Comment: NSDictionary *dict=[books objectAtIndex:i];
        AppointmentListing *book=[[AppointmentListing alloc]init];
        book.appointmentdate=[dict valueForKey:@"AppointmentDate"];
        book.AppointmentListingsID=[dict valueForKey:@"AppointmentListingsID"];
        book.AppointmentTime=[dict valueForKey:@"AppointmentTime"];
        book.PatientID=[dict valueForKey:@"PatientID"];
        book.ProviderNPI=[dict valueForKey:@"ProviderNPI"];
        book.UpdateDateTime=[dict valueForKey:@"UpdateDateTime"];

Comment: @Kukdeep i have AppoitmentListing Class in which theses all are so how add arrobject in that array

Comment: Uncomment the commented code from the code above you will have the solution.

Comment: if uncommenting that it crashed you may please edit how to do whole

Comment: Paste your crash log here, than I will edit the code according.

Comment: I am using xcode 4 may uncomment the code and also remain below code same

Answer (score 0):

From your code I presume that you are using that JSON folder for json parsing, containing many Json Parser related file...

Do one thing, First import JSON.h file:

```
#import "JSON.h"
```

Then parse your response string like this,

first create an object like this:

```
SBJSON *json = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];
NSDictionary *response_dict = [json objectWithString:json_string];
```

And you're done!!!

Comment: yes i am importing JSON,h but below that i only add this how will i add in array as i have done

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableData *responseData1= [NSMutableData data] ;
responseData1 = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://celeritas-solutions.com/emrapp/AppointmentListings.php"]];
// NSLog(@"%@",responseData1);
NSString *responseString1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//NSLog(@"REs:-->%@",responseString1);
//[responseData1 release];
responseData1 = nil;
NSMutableArray *responseArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
responseArray = (NSMutableArray *)[responseString1 JSONValue];
// NSLog(@"ghfchfvghv%@",responseArray);
//[responseString1 release];
//return responseArray;
NSLog(@"%@",[responseArray description]);
```

Answer (score 0):

//This is for the Dictionary You can use in the same way for Array.

```
NSString *url = @"http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastjson?w=22117";
NSString *myJson=[[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

if([myJson length]==0)
{
    [myJson release];
    return;
}
SBJsonParser *praser=[[SBJsonParser alloc]init];
    NSDictionary *dicParser=[[praser objectWithString:myJson error:nil] copy];
```